# How can I write this line from C in Pascal?

Tags: c, pascal

I found one piece of the code on the internet

```
int count(const char *needle, const char *stack) {
int n = 0;
const char *p;
if (*stack == 0) return 0;
if (*needle == 0) return 0;
p = strchr(stack, *needle);
if (needle[1] == 0) n += !!p;
if (p) {
    n += count(needle + 1, p + 1);
    n += count(needle, p + 1);
    }
return n;
}
```

and I know how to rewrite everything except 1 line and that is

```
p = strchr(stack, *needle);
```

I really don't know how to do this the best way, I don't even fully understand how it works in C, also, should this line

```
if (needle[1] == 0) n += !!p;
```

be

```
if (needle[1] = 0) then n:=n+ not(not(p));
```

I am not sure about that line either...

Comment: If I remember Pascal correctly, booleans are stored as `-1` for `True` and `0` for `False`. The `!!p` will return `0` if `p==0` and `1` if `p!=0` therefore the `not(not(p))` will not work.

Comment: Also, in Pascal, strings are stored differently than in C. You don't want to rewrite this program by reinterpreting lines individually.

Comment: Most Pascals use "1" for true and 0 for false and other values are undefined. My guess would be that the !! is a way to sanitize the many values of the integer to one defined value using an expression (not IF). If that is not standard behaviour of C, it probably requires checking what the original compiler did. Based on that truth tabel, you can devise an expression in Pascal.  +1 just for the fun of bringing that !! to light.

Answer (score 0):

`strchr( string, character)` looks through a string to find a character. If it succeeds it returns a pointer to the character found, otherwise it returns NULL – a null pointer.

When the pointer is subject to the boolean negation (exclamation mark operator), it behaves like a number in that the null pointer works as 0 and negation gives 1, while non-null pointer negated gives 0. Another boolean negation makes finally 0 from original null pointer and 1 from non-null pointer.

Finally, if `needle[1]` is zero, that is a `needle` string is one character long, and that character if found in `stack` string, variable `n` gets incremented by 1, otherwise it gets added zero.

Answer (score 0):

In free Pascal, there are functions which will manage null-terminated strings. It's unclear from the problem statement whether the input arguments, in Pascal, are being managed as Pascal string types, or null terminated strings. Either could be done.

The function in free Pascal corresponding to `strchr` is probably `[strscan][1]`. Assuming that you kept the arguments to the `count` function as null terminated strings (`PChar` type), then this:

```
const char *p;
p = strchr(stack, *needle);
```

Would become this:

```
var p: PChar;
...
p = strscan(stack, needle^)
```

This:

```
if (needle[1] == 0) n += !!p;
```

Would become this:

```
if (needle[1] = 0) and (p <> nil) then Inc(n);
```

If the arguments to your `count` function are Pascal strings, you can still use the above by declaring local `PChar` variables and convert them.